# Python function returning different list?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm making a Hangman game. This function is supposed to check if a guessed letter is in the word, print the progress of the guesses so far, and update the array containing the guesses. "guess" is an array of underscores, each getting replaced by the correct letter as the game progresses:

```
def check_guess(word, guess, letter):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            guess[i] = letter
            print(guess[i], end=' ')
        else:
            print('_', end=' ')
    print ('\n')
    return guess
```

So say the word is "eaten", guess is an array of five underscores, and the letter is 'e'. If I type:

```
guess = check_guess(word, guess, 'e')
```

It'll print correctly, but it won't update guess to

```
['e', '_', '_', 'e', '_']
```

It stays an array of five underscores.

In fact, it only updates the array if I code it like this:

```
def check_guess(word, guess, letter):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            guess[i] = letter
        print(guess[i], end=' ')
    print ('\n')
    return guess
```

I'm completely stumped why the longer version does not update the array, but the shorter one does. I'm doing guess[i] = letter in both.

Thanks for any help in figuring this out. I like to understand why things work when they do!

Comment: You are using a *list* not an array.

Comment: I copy-and-pasted your code, and `guess` is being updated.

Comment: Indeed, there is no need to `return` guess and reassign it to `guess`, ie. no need for `guess = check_guess(...)` since it already mutates `guess` inside the function.

Comment: You could simplify the entire function to `guess[:] = [w if w == letter else g for (w, g) in zip(word, guess)]; print(' '.join(guess))`. Also, no need to return.

Comment: The code you've shown us isn't responsible for the bug you're investigating.

Comment: Sorry for the 'array' word, I come from a Perl background. So then the scope of guess isn't limited to the function it's changed in? I thought I'd have to declare guess as global somewhere for it to change without return. Also no clue why it isn't updating on my end. I can post the whole code if it'd be helpful.

Comment: Post the minimal code that runs standalone and reproduces the error when run. This will most likely not be the "whole code" of whatever project you're working on; it should be heavily stripped down.

Comment: The problem with the broken one is that it prints "_" as an else statement if the letter doesn't match, rather than the actual state of guess which has previous guesses. It was a silly oversight. Now I'm more confused about the scope of "guess" and why the changes made in check_guess aren't solely local to that function! The internet says the scope should be limited to check_guess, even if the variable name is the same.

Comment: @ErikOlson As per your last comment(Scope issue): No, in python, scope won't be limited to that function because when you pass the guess array to this function, the array's copy is not sent, rather the reference is sent, which means that whatever you are updating in this function is being updated on the original guess array, not its copy. This is shallow_copy, but what you want to do is deep copy and shortcut for that is: guess[::] . So if your caller calls this function like this: `check_guess(word, guess[::], letter)`, then the scope of the guess parameter is limited to `check_guess`

Answer (score 0):

well. first things first.

your code wont work for sintax issues. apparently you are trying to set a variable inside a print command, not sure why.

```
def check_guess(word, guess, letter):
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] == letter:
        guess[i] = letter
        print(guess[i], end=' ')
    else:
        print('_', end=' ')
print ('\n')
return guess
```

Results:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-14d09305bfe6>", line 5
    print(guess[i], end=' ')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So lets disconsider "end" for a while to see exactly what your function is doing:

it asks for three parameters; word, guess, letter. 
it goes through each letter in word in an uncoventional way (instead of getting the positions and reffering to 'em, you could just get the letters pretty straighforward) 
it checks if the letter given == the letter at word 
if so, it associates the letter at guess 
and prints the letter 
else it prints an underline 
it returns the updated guess

Okay. So apparently guess could (should) be a global variable, as well as the "word".
Maybe it would be cleaner/wiser to only pass the letter as a function parameter. 
 It would also be cleaner to go through each letter in the word instead of the position indexer, but at the same time we can enumerate it so we know how to refer to the guess variable. 
 Also, besides printing one letter at a time, we can just print the whole guess at the end of the function. 
 Also, if its a game you want it to be interative/recurrent until the player wins or loses, so it shld be inside a loop.

My version, wld look like this:

first part:

```
## declaring main variables ##

word = "Upvote this if helpful"

word = word.lower()

guess = list('_'*len(word))

for position, letter in enumerate(word):

    if letter == ' ':

        guess[position] = ' '

trials = 5

breaker = False
```

game function:

```
## defining guess function ##

def guess_function(letter):

    letter = letter.lower()

    missed_guess = True

    global trials
    global guess
    global breaker
    global word

    for position, word_letter in enumerate(word):

        if letter == word_letter:

            missed_guess = False

            guess[position] = letter

    if missed_guess:

        trials = trials - 1

        print ('Letter %s not in word. You lose 1 trial. You got %d chances left!\n' %(letter, trials))

        if trials == 0:

            print ('Oh no! You lost! The word was: %s' %word)
            breaker = True

        return

    else:

        if '_' in guess:

            print ('Word so far: %s\n%s chances left! Keep it going!\n' %(''.join(guess), trials))

        else:

            print ('You made it! The word was:\n%s\n\nCONGRATS!!' %(''.join(guess)))

            breaker = True

        return
```

game on:

```
breaker = False

while breaker==False:

    input_letter = raw_input("Give me a letter!")

    guess_function(input_letter)
```

sample game:

```
Give me a letter!a
Letter a not in word. You lose 1 trial. You got 4 chances left!

Give me a letter!u
Word so far: u_____ ____ __ _____u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!p
Word so far: up____ ____ __ ___p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!v
Word so far: upv___ ____ __ ___p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!o
Word so far: upvo__ ____ __ ___p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!t
Word so far: upvot_ t___ __ ___p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!e
Word so far: upvote t___ __ _e_p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!h
Word so far: upvote th__ __ he_p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!i
Word so far: upvote thi_ i_ he_p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!s
Word so far: upvote this i_ he_p_u_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!f
Word so far: upvote this if he_pfu_
4 chances left! Keep it going!
Give me a letter!l
You made it! The word was:
upvote this if helpful

CONGRATS!!
```

Comment: OP is using Python3 which has the `print` function. You can also use it in some versions of Python2 by `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. It's a silly "else" oversight:

```
if word[i] == letter:
    guess[i] = letter
    print(guess[i], end=' ')
else:
    print('_', end=' ')
```

The code is saying if the letter matches, print it. Otherwise, print _ no matter what even if the list `guess` does not have "_" at that position. D'oh!

My bigger question now is why would `guess` when used in check_guess be a global variable? Shouldn't I need to say `return guess` for the list to update when called outside of this particular function? I can start another question if that would be best.

Answer (score -1):

```
def check_guess(word, guess, letter):
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] == letter:
        guess.append(letter)
    else:
        guess.append("_")
print ('\n')
return guess
guess=[]
check_guess("eaten", guess, 'e')
```

This works for me and updates guess. For the first one you need to define an empty list >> guess first then add to it as you go by.